# Append elements of list to dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a random text file and want to put all its words into a dict, because I have to count them.

```
raw_data = open("ipsum.txt", "r").readlines()

data = []
word_dict = {

    'word' : 0

}

for lines in raw_data:

   lines = lines.strip('\n')
   data.append(lines.split(" "))


print(data)

for word in data:
    if word not in word_dict:
        word_dict[word] = 0
```

But I always get the following error message:

```
  if word not in word_dict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I don't know how to continue.

Comment: data is a list of lists. You either need to add another loop, or flatten it (e.g. using extend rather than append to start with)

Comment: If you just want to count words, you should use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much easier and cleaner solution would be the following:

```py
file = open("ipsum.txt", "r")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k,v
```

And a more pythonic way would be:

```py
from collections import Counter
file = open("ipsum.txt", "r")
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())
```

You can sort them as well by using

```py
wordcount = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=true)
```